# Cannot use rootView when initialising a variable

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

HorizontalBarChart barChart = (HorizontalBarChart)rootView.findViewById(R.id.barchartnew);


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);


    HorizontalBarChart barChart = (HorizontalBarChart)rootView.findViewById(R.id.barchartnew);

return rootView;
}

public void test(){

//Here I want to access barChart


}
```

In the above code I am trying to access the variable `barChart` from the method `test()`. However when I try and initialise it at the top under `public class Tab1 extends Fragment {` I get `Cannot resolve symbol 'rootView'`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Makes sense. `rootView` is a variable local to your `onCreateView()` method. In the top one just use `HorizontalBarChart barChart;` and initialize it in `onCreateView()`.

Comment: How am I suppose to initialise the variable then?

Comment: Yes, but when I use `HorizontalBarChart barChart;` at the top, I don't get access to all its features from the other method `test()`

Comment: What do you mean by "_I don't get access to all its features from the other method_"?

Comment: I want to use `barchart.invalidate()` in the method `test()`. But this only works when it has been properly initialised in the `onCreateView()` method.

Comment: Well it should be initialized by the time `test()` is called. Are there any errors shown?

Comment: yes, `barchart.invalidate()` the `.invalidate()` cannot be resolved @ProgrammingMachine5000

Comment: And they can if you leave the first line unchanged? Are they even implemented?

Comment: Is what even implemented?

Comment: The `.invalidate()` methods.

Comment: yes the `.invalidate()` is implemented but only works when it has been initialised as `(HorizontalBarChart)rootView.findViewById(R.id.barchartnew);`

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Can you print the whole error log? I don't know how your `HorizontalBarChart` is implemented for other `View`s it works on my system.